# Jquery and form with same name issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Well i'm working on a small php script and in the admin panel i've added a page to manage comments. Following is the html markup for comment:

```
<form name="form" action="">
<tr>
 <td>COMMENT ID</td><td><button value="0" name="choice">Delete</button><button value="1" name="choice">Accept</button></td>
</form>
```

For every comment i'm posting this info to a file `comment.php` using the following jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").submit(function(){
            $.get("response.php", $(this).serialize(), function(a){ 
                $("#info").html(a)
            });
            return false
        })
    });
</script>
```

My issue is i can't get the `choice` Value using this code `$_REQUEST['choice']` because both `<button>`s have the same name and this is the same thing for forms. How can i fix this ?

Comment: Both buttons submit the form ! right ? you need to make a separate event for each button using `$.click()`

Comment: how can i do it ? you should know that both of button are on the same form and they're with the same name but with different value and the i need to get the value of the clicked button ! how can i do this please  @hutchbat

Comment: As a side note that html looks invalid... `<tr><td>` should be inside a `<table>`, not `<form>`

Comment: @TilwinJoy There is a table before form :)

Comment: @user3756377 still it's invalid because `<tr>` is a child of `<form>`..

Comment: @TilwinJoy so i shoudld make <form><tr> or <tr><form> ?

Comment: `<tr>` should be direct child of `<table>` (neglecting `<thead>`, `<tbody>` etc). so it'd be `<tr><form>..</form></tr>` and if you need to use table structure inside form it'd be like `<form><table><tr>..</tr></table></form>`. Also note that you're not closing the `<tr>` in shared code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are some mistakes on your code:

1) You forgot to put the `id` attribute that your JS is calling

```
<form name="form" action="">
```

Change it to this:

```
<form name="form" action="" id="form">
```

Since it has the same name, use the `.click()` event instead.

Complete Code:

```
<form name="form" action="" id="form">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>COMMENT ID</td>
            <td>
                <button value="0" name="choice">Delete</button>
                <button value="1" name="choice">Accept</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="100">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button[name='choice']").click(function(e){
        var form_data = {};
        form_data.choice = $(this).val();
        form_data.id = $(this).siblings('input[name="id"]').val();
        e.preventDefault(); // stops the normal submission
        $.post("index.php", form_data, function(a){ 
            console.log(a); // check the values on browser console
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

On your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['choice'])) {
    $action = $_POST['choice'];
    $data = $_POST;
    // its inside $_POST['id'];
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wwh5Zg)

Comment: I know the mistake was made while copying my code to stakoverflow otherwise your code doesnt work @kevinabelita

Comment: @user3756377 i don't understand how you get two different things while *copying*... btw, we can only help you regarding what you post, we don't have sixth sense.. :) personally i don't think posting "*your code doesn't work*" below an answer that points out your mistakes is encouraging to get any help..

Comment: @TilwinJoy lol I'm sorry but i really need your help ! Just tell me how to use two button with same name but when i receive only the value of the clicked one ?

Comment: @TilwinJoy Worked like charm thank you so so much brother ! i have something else in the same form i have an input like this <input type="hidden" value="ID" name="ID"> Can i get it with the button value or no ?

Comment: @user3756377 yes you just have to include and on to the form, wait il edit a sec.

Comment: @user3756377 I'm not the guy who answered..! :D

Comment: Unfortunatly because all forms have this input hidden i get the same value for all forms :(

Comment: @user3756377 well thats gonna happen because most probably there are many names that share this name of this hidden input, is it close to the button? since the complete markup is not available in this question, my only guess is to use the `.closest()` method

Comment: Is it's just after the button decline <input type="hidden" name="id" value="36"> how can i use closet ?

Comment: @user3756377 wait, could you clarify? is it next to the buttons `delete` and `accept`? maybe you could edit your question so that we could see where it is in the markup, its hard to guess really

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56018/discussion-between-user3756377-and-kevinabelita).

Comment: @user3756377 oh okay, its one of their siblings. you can use `.siblings()` check the edit now

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO SO SO MUCH WORK PERFECTLY ! FINALLY

Comment: @user3756377 sure no prob! glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by binding the ajax request to the `button.click()` instead of `form.submit()`

```
$(function(){ // $(document).ready() shorthand
    $("button[name=choice]").click(function(){
        var data = 'choice='+ $(this).val() + '&' + $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        $.get("response.php", data, function(a){ 
            $("#info").html(a)
        });
        return false
    })
});
```

Comment: i'll fix it in 1 sec.

Comment: It worked well for the choise but i get the same value for the input in all forms

Comment: You've not mentionned that you have multiple forms, you've used the form ID in you're code and since IDs are unique i've thought it is only one form.

Comment: They're are many forms with same name and two buttons with same id and  an hidden input with same id in all forms please help me brother !

Comment: I've update the code again to work with multiple buttons inside multiple forms, however you need to paste the whole HTML if you need more help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56017/discussion-between-user3756377-and-hutchbat).